# Make a responsive timeline in html / CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to do navigation like this:
[image: http://ifelselab.com/sass/1.jpg]
[image: http://ifelselab.com/sass/2.jpg]
[image: http://ifelselab.com/sass/3.jpg]

how i can make this responsive ?

This is my current code, but I don't think it's responsive:

HTML

```
<figure class="pagenation"> 
        <a href="#1" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider" class="colone">adddddddd</a>
        <a href="#2" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider" class="coltwo">adddddddd</a>
        <a href="#3" data-liquidslider-ref="main-slider" class="colthree">adddddddd</a>

      </figure>
```

CSS

```
#one {position:absolute;top:200px;background-image: url('imgact/a1.png');}
#one:hover {background-image: url('imgact/a1-over.png');}
.onehold {background-position: left bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 725px;height:130px;z-index: 4}

#two {position:absolute;top:238px;background-image: url('imgact/a2.png');}
#two:hover {background-image: url('imgact/a2-over.png');}
.twohold {background-position: left bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 725px;height:171px;z-index: 3}

#three {position:absolute;top:325px;background-image: url('imgact/3.png');display:inline-block;text-indent: 9999999px}
#three:hover {background-image: url('imgact/3over.png');}
.threehold {background-position: left bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 725px;height:171px;z-index: 2;}


#four {position:absolute;top:432px;background-image: url('imgact/4.png');}
#four:hover {background-image: url('imgact/4over.png');}
.fourhold {background-position: left bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 725px;height:171px;z-index: 1}
```

Comment: Don't use px values, but percentage values instead (for the widths). Should this "navigation" be draggable (the black box)?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this heirarchy and levels in your code (I have nothing to do with your sub-classes like onehold, twohold, ... Those are actually good IMHO.) :

**THE TIMELINE (THE WHOLE) > DIFFERENT BLOCKS (Subset of your "Whole", like your .onehold, ...) > SECTIONS AND LINKS IN YOUR BLOCKS**

(Assuming your whole timeline isn't in a fixed container like 960px so that it can shrink or expand in your webpage)

1st Level : Your whole timeline, It's gonna have a `width` of like `90%` of your page. The amount isn't important, just the percentage width.

2nd Level : If you have certain number of blocks, do a math with your favourite calculator to determine every block's width. (If you have 4 block then each should be `25%`)
If not, I think you have to use some JavaScript magic and let it calculate the width for you as your number of blocks grow over time.

3rd Level : Your links, this is gonna be different in your various classes depending on how many links they will hold. Then, based on that certain number you specify `margin`s in percentage.

I think this is gonna solve your problem and lose the `px` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answers i solved problem with "  %  " there is my code

```
.pagenation {position:absolute;float:left;margin-left:100px;margin-top: 0px;text-indent: -9999px;display: inline-block;background-image: url('ruler.png');background-size:100%;width:525px;text-align: left}
        .pagenation a{ text-align: left}

        .colone {width: 20%;top:8px;left:1px;height: 10px;background-color: black !important;display: block; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;position: relative;}
        .colone:hover {float:left;display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .colone:active {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .colone:visited {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .coltwo {width: 240px;top:-3px;left:199px;height: 10px;background-color: black !important;display: block; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;position: relative;}
        .coltwo:hover {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .coltwo:active {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .coltwo:visited {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .colthree {width:74px;top:-12px;left:450px;height: 10px;background-color: black !important;display: block; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;position: relative;}
        .colthree:hover {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .colthree:active {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
        .colthree:visited {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}


  /* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 




 }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { 



 }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { 

    .thumbcontainer {margin-top: 150px;width: 100%;margin-left: 10%}  
    .pagenation {background-size: 100%;width:67%;height:30px;margin-left: 30px}
    .colone {width: 20%;top:8px;left:1px;height: 10px;background-color: black !important;display: block; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;position: relative;}
      .colone:hover {float:left;display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .colone:active {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .colone:visited {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .coltwo {width: 20%;top:-3px;left:199px;height: 10px;background-color: black !important;display: block; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;position: relative;}
      .coltwo:hover {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .coltwo:active {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .coltwo:visited {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .colthree {width:20%;top:-12px;left:450px;height: 10px;background-color: black !important;display: block; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 0); /* For IE */
  opacity: 0.0;position: relative;}
      .colthree:hover {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .colthree:active {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}
      .colthree:visited {display: block;background-color: black; zoom: 1; filter: alpha(opacity = 100); /* For IE */
  opacity: 1.0;}


 }
```